# Reading theme1.xml from a .docx, attribute without namespace

Tags: c++, docx, libopc

Im making a docx reader (libopc and C++) and I have problem when I want to get the minor and major Font from the theme1.xml. The problem is that I dont know how I have to write the namespace for attributes without it:

```
<a:latin typeface="Calibri"/>
```

I have tryed with:

```
mce_start_attribute(&reader, _X(""), _X("typeface")) {//type
    _majorFont = (char*) xmlTextReaderConstValue(reader.reader);
}mce_end_attribute(&reader);
```

and:

```
mce_start_attribute(&reader, _X("http://www.3w.org/2000/xmlns"), _X("typeface")) {//type
    _majorFont = (char*) xmlTextReaderConstValue(reader.reader);
}mce_end_attribute(&reader);
```

And I get the same result: nothing.

Any Suggestion.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Somebody can create the tag [libopc]? My reputation does not allow me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer myself.
After ckeck libopc source code the solution is set namespace value in mce_start_attribute macro as NULL:

```
mce_start_attribute(&reader, NULL, _X("typeface")) {//type
    _majorFont = (char*) xmlTextReaderConstValue(reader.reader);
}mce_end_attribute(&reader);
```